# Re-calculate total_tax on cart and checkout

Tags: woocommerce

I need a solution to re-calculate the total tax amount.

Is there an easy solution to just overwrite it?

This was my approach:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'calc_total_tax', 10, 1 );
function calc_total_tax( $cart_object ) {

    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {

        // actual taxes which are calculated in another method
        $tax = floatval(123);

        $cart_object->set_total_tax( $tax );

    }

}
```

My debugger is showing the right value for `$cart_object->totals['total_tax']` but the output is still the old value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Found the solution:

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'calc_total_tax', 10, 1 );
function calc_total_tax( $cart_object ) {

  if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {

    // actual taxes which are calculated in another method
    $tax = floatval(123);

    $cart_object->set_cart_contents_taxes( [1 => $tax] );

  }

}
```

Comment: Though this is adding to the checkout as a Tax entry, it is not adding to the cart total. How did you get it working?